# On the operators from $l_{p}$ into Tsirelson's space $T$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $1<p<2$. My question is: Is any operator from $l_{p}$ into Tsirelson's space $T$ compact?

Comment: Yes.  Same argument that works into $\ell_1$.

Comment: @BillJohnson, of course if by the Tsirelson space Dongyang understands your version, namely the dual of the original construction. In the case of the *original Tsierlson space*, non-compact operators exist.

Comment: Is my question true for $p\geq 2$?

Comment: @TomekKania: In the case of the original Tsierlson space, non-compact operators exist. Could you tell me the relevant reference? Thank you.

Comment: @DongyangChen, take $p>1$. Then $X$ is finite-dimensional if and only if all weakly $p$-summable sequences in $X$ are norm-null and the closed unit ball of $X$ is weakly $p$-compact. Now, the latter property is enjoyed by the original Tsierlson space (this must be proved somewhere in the Casazza-Schura book). However the former condition is equivalent to compactness of all operators from $(\ell_p)^*$ to $X$.

Comment: @TomekKania, I am not sure that there exists a non-compact operator from $l_{p}$ into  the original Tsierlson space for $1<p<2$. But I am sure that every operator from  $l_{p}$ into  the original Tsierlson space is compact for $2<p<\infty$.

Comment: @DongyangChen, If I understand your question and the earlier comments correctly then maybe the paper *Remarks on some basic properties of Tsirelson's space* by Castillo and Sanchez may be of interest to you; the paper can be found at http://siba-ese.unisalento.it/index.php/notemat/article/view/1304

Comment: @PhilipBrooker, Thank you for providing the paper. I'll read it.

Comment: @BillJohnson, Does the Tsirelson space $T$(your version, not the original Tsirelson space)contain normalized weakly $p$-summable sequences for any $1<p<\infty$?

Comment: No, Dongyang. Every operator from $\ell_p$ into $T$ is compact for every $1<p$.